# Copy <li> and insert them after themselves

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to copy contents of each of my `<ul>`'s of selected class, so that

```
<ul class="testowyUl">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

will change to

```
<ul class="testowyUl">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

It seemed simple, but for some reason I cannot make it work. The problem is, that I'm using class (as there are going to be multiple lists of that type), and I do not know how to select my `<ul>` and then perform `clone()` and `append()`. I tried chaining with `$(".testowyUl").children().clone().after(".testowyUl");` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.append()` with a function as argument:

```
$(".testowyUl").append(function(){return $(this).children().clone();});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

```
$(".testowyUl").each(function() {
    $("li",this).clone().appendTo(this);
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SDe8R/2/)

Comment: This does not work with two lists as the OP wanted. http://jsfiddle.net/SDe8R/1/ What happens is that the *entire* contents of *all* the lists with that class name are cloned, and then appended within *each one* of the lists with that class name.

Comment: as Joseph said, it does not work with multiple lists unfortunately

Comment: @Joseph Myers: thanks, missed the part where he said that he had more than one `ul`

Comment: You're welcome. It works now. I knew you could fix it, so I didn't even bother trying to give my own answer.